# Simple low level implementation of HTTP(S) proxy is not working

Tags: java, sockets, https, http-proxy

I am implementing simple HTTP(S) proxy/tunnel in Java. All done in multithreaded application which uses sockets for creating tunnel. The code I came up with works just fine with HTTP, but it doesn't work with HTTPS. The issue I get is that the last server in chain (means of my tunnel) throws connection timeout when tries to open socket connection to destination server.

In other words with HTTPS connection:

```
Request:
client ---> tunnel-srv1 ---> tunnel-srv2 ---> HTTPS-server (https://facebook.com for example)
                                            ^ Timeout here on new Socket("facebook.com", 443);
```

tunnel-srv1 (omitting irrelevant code):

```
public class ConnectionMainThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Socket remoteSocket;

    public ConnectionMainThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Open connection to tunnel-srv2 server
            remoteSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8081);

            // Create thread client->remote
            Thread clientToRemote = new ReceiveSendThread(clientSocket, remoteSocket, true);
            clientToRemote.start();

            // Create thread remote->client
            Thread remoteToClient = new ReceiveSendThread(remoteSocket, clientSocket);
            remoteToClient.start();

            // Block thread until both other threads are released
            clientToRemote.join();
            remoteToClient.join();

            // Make sure all the connection are closed
            remoteSocket.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ReceiveSendThread extends Thread {

    private Socket inSocket;
    private Socket outSocket;
    private boolean isFromClient = false;

    public ReceiveSendThread(Socket inSocket, Socket outSocket, boolean isFromClient) {
        this.inSocket = inSocket;
        this.outSocket = outSocket;
        this.isFromClient = isFromClient;
    }

    public ReceiveSendThread(Socket inSocket, Socket outSocket) {
        this.inSocket = inSocket;
        this.outSocket = outSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (
            OutputStream out = outSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = inSocket.getInputStream();
        ) {
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];

            if (this.isFromClient) {
                nRead = in.read(data, 0 ,data.length);
                byte[] first = new byte[4096];
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, first, 0, first.length);
                String str = new String(first);
                String uri = (str.split(" "))[1];
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                String host = url.getURL();
                byte[] bytes = host.getBytes();
                byte[] firstLine = new byte[4096];
                System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, firstLine, 0, bytes.length);
                out.write(firstLine);
                out.flush();
                out.write(data, 0, nRead);
                out.flush();
            }


            while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0 ,data.length)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, nRead);
                out.flush();
            }

            // Input socket is closing
            outSocket.shutdownOutput();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class URL {

    private String protocol = "http";
    private String host = null;
    private String port = null;
    private String path = "/";

    public URL(String str) throws MalformedURLException {
        int protoPos = str.indexOf("://");
        if (protoPos != -1) {
            str = str.substring(protoPos+3);
        }
        int pathPos = str.indexOf("/");
        if (pathPos == 0) {
            throw new MalformedURLException("no hostname present");
        }
        if (pathPos > 0) {
            str = str.substring(0, pathPos);
        }
        int portDelimiterPos = str.indexOf(":");
        if (portDelimiterPos == -1) {
            port = getDefaultPort();
            host = str;
        } else {
            port = str.substring(portDelimiterPos + 1);
            host = str.substring(0, portDelimiterPos);
        }
    }

    public String getURL(){
        return host+":"+port;
    }

    private String getDefaultPort(){
        String port;
        switch (this.protocol){
            case "http":
                port = "80";
                break;
            case "https":
                port = "443";
                break;
            case "ws":
                port = "80";
                break;
            default:
                port = "80";
        }
        return port;
    }
}
```

tunnel-srv2 (omitting irrelevant code):

```
public class ConnectionMainThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Socket remoteSocket;

    private InetAddress addr;
    private Integer port;
    private String str;

    public ConnectionMainThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Find remote server location (read first line)
            InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];

            nRead = in.read(data, 0 ,data.length);
            if (nRead < 0) {
                clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                clientSocket.close();
                return;
            }
            str = new String(data, 0, nRead);
            String[] res = str.split("\\:");
            String host = res[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(res[1].replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
            addr = Inet4Address.getByName(host);
            //String addr = host;


            // Open connection to destination server
            remoteSocket = new Socket(addr, port);

            // Create thread client->remote
            Thread clientToRemote = new ReceiveSendThread(clientSocket, remoteSocket, true);
            clientToRemote.start();

            // Create thread remote->client
            Thread remoteToClient = new ReceiveSendThread(remoteSocket, clientSocket);
            remoteToClient.start();

            // Block thread until both other threads are released
            clientToRemote.join();
            remoteToClient.join();

            // Make sure all the connection are closed
            remoteSocket.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class ReceiveSendThread extends Thread {

    private Socket inSocket;
    private Socket outSocket;
    private boolean dump = false;

    public ReceiveSendThread(Socket inSocket, Socket outSocket, boolean dump) {
        this.inSocket = inSocket;
        this.outSocket = outSocket;
        this.dump = dump;
    }

    public ReceiveSendThread(Socket inSocket, Socket outSocket) {
        this.inSocket = inSocket;
        this.outSocket = outSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (
            OutputStream out = outSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = inSocket.getInputStream();
        ) {
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];

            while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0 ,data.length)) != -1) {
                if (this.dump) {
                    System.out.print(new String(data, 0, nRead));
                }
                out.write(data, 0, nRead);
                out.flush();
            }

            // Input socket is closing
            outSocket.shutdownOutput();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't flush inside copy loops. The final `System.arraycopy()` in the `if (this.isFromClient)` block is unnecessary: just write `bytes`. There seems to be a write-length bug here too. Shutdown before close is redundant.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I will use your suggestion for improvement. Any idea on why HTTPS does not work? These changes doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: They were posted as comments. If I had thought they would fix it I would have posted them as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original issue is not in the code, but rather in the logic.

From [RFC documentation](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt):

```
A CONNECT method requests that a proxy establish a tunnel connection
on its behalf.
```

This means that proxy upon receiving CONNECT request should establish tunnel to the destination and in its turn it means that CONNECT request is not meant to reach destination and is only for the proxy server, whereas code in the question will also send this request to the destination. Despite RFC mentioning that in this case server that receives this request to itself may respond with 2xx code, it is not mandatory and seems it is not how it works with servers it was tested on.

So the solution is actually parse the incoming request properly and in case of receiving CONNECT request just open connection and not send it to the destination.

Comment: Accept own answer, since changing implementation proved it to be correct... Should read specs more often